# Trying to pass parameter back to custom hook to emit login data

Tags: javascript, reactjs, socket.io, react-hooks, use-effect

I have a login form component. I'm trying to pass `email` and `password` to a custom hook, where I emit the login information.

I am having trouble getting the values into the custom hook which is in it's own `useSocket.js` file:

```
export function useLogIn() {
  const [email, setEmail] = useState();
  const [password, setPassword] = useState();

  useEffect(() => {
    if(email != "" && password != "")
    {
      socket.emit('signin', {"inputEmail": email, "inputPassword": password});
    }
  }, [])
}
```

Here is the login component:

```
const LoginView = () => {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const response = useIsLoggedIn();
  const loginData = useLogIn();

  let email;
  let password;

  const checkLogin = () => {
    if (response ? response.success : false == true) {
      navigate("/app/dashboard");
    } else {
      navigate("/");
    }
  }

  const login = () => {
    loginData.setEmail(email);
    loginData.setPassword(password);
    console.log("email: " + email);
    console.log("password: " + password);
  }

  //listen to login and update page
  useEffect(checkLogin, response ? response.success : false);
```

And here is what happens when the form submits:

```
initialValues={{
              email: email,
              password: password
            }}
onSubmit={() => {
              login();
            }}
```

Any help is appreciated, thank you.